# What sci-fi references are made in "This Giant Papier Mache Boulder Is Actually Really Heavy"

Tags: b-movies

Which classic sci-fi films and TV shows are referenced in the New Zealand indie sci-fi comedy title:

[*This Giant Papier Mache Boulder Is Actually Really Heavy* (2016)?](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4231486)

The ones I have so far, mentioned by characters are:

- Star Wars,
- Blakes 7,
- Star Trek,
- Lost In Space

Visual/indirect references:

- Dune (man with water bottles when they enter the cinema)
- The Day the Earth Stood Still (referred to via the Klaatu system)
- Battlestar Galactica (via the Adama Quadrant space region)

Which other sci-fi films/TV shows/books are referenced?
NB: they mostly seem to be pre-1980s.

Comment: It's not clear why this question was closed. No reason was given apart from "off-topic". 
It's a question about a sci-fi movie, which seems on topic, and fits in the categories of "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" and "Plot, character, or setting explanations".
This question seems better suited here than in movies stackexchange.

Comment: FWIW I'm 99% sure this would be closed on [movies.se] for their Trivia close reason. I voted to close this as off topic, though I think I chose the wrong close reason, and this is more "needs more focus" (previously too broad). This is really a list question, although finite, which don't really fit into the Q/A format of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot we have plenty of list questions which would be a lot longer than I can imagine this one every being.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot How is this question different from all the random "Identify all the characters in this sketch" question?  The only difference I can see is that the medium being inspected is a movie and not an image.

Comment: @PeterM Well that's a controversial subject in itself.

Comment: TheLethalCarrot - not helped by the fact that a lot of the Sci-Fi outfits and references seem to be generic sci-fi tropes rather than a *direct parody of a particular property*.